# Android: How to avoid restart after Animation finish?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

the image will go back to 0,0 after animation finish
how to set not go back?
still stay in 100,100

```
Animation am = new TranslateAnimation((float)0(), (float)100, (float)0,(float)100);

am.setDuration(5000);
am.setRepeatCount(0);
point.startAnimation(am);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Animation.setFillAfter(true)` to persist the final animation state.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set. Note that this applies to individual animations and when using an AnimationSet to chain animations.

```
Animation am = new TranslateAnimation((float)0(), (float)100, (float)0,(float)100);

am.setDuration(5000);
am.setFillAfter(true);
am.setRepeatCount(0);
point.startAnimation(am);
```